# Finding the Meta site

Tags: support

Just out of curiosity: If a new user can't find out how to get to the Meta site, where is he supposed to ask? On the main site, or on Meta? (I didn't see any directions on the [What's Meta](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) page, but it was too long to read the whole thing. At one time, before the site was redesigned, the Meta button was not so well hidden.)

Comment: I couldn't find meta on the app this morning until I added it to some sort of list... it's fairly easy on the website, I'd say.

Comment: I don't know. I guess clicking "StackExchange" is easy. I have no idea whether it was easy for me four years ago, and the site design was different back then anyway.

Comment: I'd think the bigger problem is a new user realizing that a "meta site" *exists* and what kind of questions should go there...which is why we have a dedicated migration path to meta for when newbies mistakenly ask meta questions on main. Problem already solved, maybe?

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with Ixrec about users finding out about Meta when they ask a Meta question.

Comment: Am I the only one who sees a prominent "Featured on Meta" box on the right hand side of my screen?

Comment: @user14111 - If they RTFM, they'll learn about Meta that way.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to find & get to the Meta site.

- There's a prominent link in the ["What's Meta?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) FAQ page.
- It's mentioned on the privileges page; ["Participate in Meta"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta)
- It's mentioned in the "[What Questions are on-topic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" page
- Featured Meta questions appear on the right-hand side of the front page (if there are any) along with hot meta posts.

[image]

- There's a link in the SE drop-down.

[image]

- If you visit your user profile, it's there.

[image]

- It's in the drop-down under "help".

[image]

- Interestingly, there's also a link to Meta under the "feedback" button at the bottom of the front page.

[image]

Comment: -1 because the big red arrows go RLRRL instead of alternating RLRLR  :)

Comment: @ward - Only the 4th picture has a circle